# Init.d script trouble shooting

Tags: root-access, lg-g3, disable-app, init.d

I'm trying to run an init.d script when my rom boots to disable system services, and they aren't running.

The script is as follows

```
#!/system/bin/sh
su -c pm disable com.google.android.gms/.update.SystemupdateService
su -c pm disable com.google.android.gms/.update.SystemUpdateGcmTaskService
```

I can confirm that normal pm disable commands work to disable non system applications. So I suspect I'm not doing something right to su privileges.

Comment: Did you set the right permissions (0755, rwxr-xr-x) on the script?

Comment: Yes the kitchen applies the appropriate permissions or if not the kitchen the rom itself when it boots. I can try to make one from scratch and test on my dd. I'm running multirom but I'm at work so I can't make a new build atm.

Comment: If you think the script itself isn't executing, try adding a line where it creates a file or echos something in logcat, so as to eliminate this factor.

Comment: So somthing like mkdir /system/test

Comment: In `/data` if you want to know if the script itself runs, and in `/system` if you want to know if `su` works well in the script.

Comment: Do you have any other script that work. If you are on stock rom you probably don't have init.d support.

Comment: So the script itself apparently isn't running. I just tried a new script with correct permissions with mkdir /data/test and rebooted checked afterwards and it's not there. I know I added init.d support to the boot image so it's there, but why wouldn't it be running?

Comment: @user199849 well if that doesn't work either than is OS  related problem. Try with some apps fron play store kernel adiutor have init.d emulator I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't done this way then try it:
Put this script in file and save it in system/bin/ (let's say you name it script1) and set permissions to 755, than make file in system/etc/init.d/ (name it whatever you want) and in file write:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
script1
```

And also set permissions to 755. Reboot and see if it has any effect.
Also you can try enabling su during boot, you have that option in super su.

Comment: Would that be my original script that I put in system/bin? Also would I need the #!/system/bin/sh header?

Comment: Yes, this what you written in your question. Yes you need that.

Comment: Didn't work either. Is there a log I could check to try to find out why it isn't working? I've never had to check a log before so idk where they are or the adb command to pull it up.

Comment: Don't know about that, but obviously somthing is wrong with init.d, so use some emulator from google play. Or assembly kernel again.

Comment: So I'm trying the same thing with su.d support in my rom. But pm disable isn't workthing there either. Is there any other command to use to disable packages/services with a script?

Comment: @user199849 For this you want to disable there is app on olay store called "Disable service" try it.

Comment: I've been using this app to check if the service has been disabled. However my main issue is meeding at way to disable them on first boot of the rom I'm building so that the user doesn't get the ota. I can confirm su.d is working with mkdir /data/test and it works. However pm commands with or with su -c are not working.

Comment: Sorry I ment with or without su -c.

Comment: When you create the script in system/bin/ and give right permissions (this from your question) and run it from terminal does it work?

Comment: Yes when I manually trigger the script it works just fine. I didn't call su from terminal emulator either su worked from the script.

Comment: @user199849 Are you open to using init.d altermatives?